# Navigation Drawer Activity: move from fragment to fragment on button click

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

Moving to another fragment from a fragment on a button click, is resulting on overlaying content like below[image]. When i click on button, both home and slideshow fragments are displaying.

Code I have used to switch from home fragment to slideshow fragment using a button in `HomeFragment.java`

```java
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        homeViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_home);
        homeViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
                textView.setText(s);
            }
        });

    Button button = root.findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, new SlideshowFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    });
    return root;
    }
```

XML for Button in `fragment_home.xml`

```xml
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.854"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.241" />
```

`container` is in `content_main.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Steps to reproduce the issue:

1. Create new project using Navigation drawer activity
2. Add a button in `fragment_home.xml`
3. Create listener for button in `HomeFragment.java`

What I am missing to display the slideshow fragment alone on button click?

`MainActivity.java` for refrence

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }

}
```

Comment: Where you define the container nav_host_fragment?

Comment: in `content_main.xml`.

Comment: Why are you using navcontroller and also replacing the fragment by your self?

Answer (score 0):

Ok got  your problem , replace  nav_host_fragment with slide_show_container (FrameLayout). name can be same idea is to replace fragment with Framelayout.

In Home activity on create add this code

```
               getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, new HomeFragment())
                .commit();
```

And remove the code suggested before.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Using `slide_show_container` also results same as both fragments are overlaying

Comment: updated the answer. put this block inside the home fragment below the button. and also use getChildFragmentManager() instead getragmentManager()

Comment: Still both are displaying